# SecondaryTable with Where Constraint

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

What is the best solution in my scenario?

I have a lagacy database and want to access the data by using a single hibernate entity. I want to keep the java part as simple as possible.

My database consists of three tables:

1. Table1(id,Att1,Att2)
2. Table2(id,Att3)
3. Table3(id,current,Att4)

I used the `@SecondaryTable` anonntaion like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")
@SecondaryTables({
  @SecondaryTable(name = "Table2", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")),
  @SecondaryTable(name = "Table3", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
})
public class Entity implements Serializable {
  int id;
  int Att1;
  int Att2;
  int Att3;
  int Att4;
}
```

This works totally fine for `Table2` and `Att3`. However, in Table3 I only want `Att4` if `current = true`. Assuming old versions of Att4 are kept in `Table3`. Can this be done by `@SecondaryTable` or do I need another approach? I would prefer to keep a single entity and not use @OneToMany by creating a unneccesary Table3 entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about adding the `current` to your entity?

```
public class Entity implements Serializable {
  int  id;
  int  Att1;
  int  Att2;
  int  Att3;
  int  Att4;
  byte current;
}
```

From the other side if you are after the best solution here I would go for making a change down in the SQL Server. Thanks to that you would get the biggest performance advantage you can have, as SQL Server cardinality estimator will be able to create the most optimal execution plan. This will limit the number of unnecessary SQL Server transactions wasted on transformation as well as amount of data transferred between the app and the database. All you need to do will be on the SQL Server side:

```
CREATE VIEW [YourEntityOnDB]
AS
SELECT t1.[id], t1.[Att1], t1.[Att2], t2.[Att3], t3.[Att4]
FROM [Table1] t1
JOIN [Table2] t2 ON t1.[id] = t2.[id]
JOIN [Table3] t3 ON t1.[id] = t3.[id]
WHERE t3.[current] = 1;
```

And the your JAVA part will be really as easy as possible as `[YourEntityOnDB]` will be the only object you would call and it will contain all id, Att1, Att2, Att3, Att4 and current = 1 in it.
On top of that based on the data uniqueness and your needs you can apply some indexes (even index your new view) to make it run even faster. In recent versions (SQL Server 2014+) there are even in-memory options to make it lighting fast if needed. There is a number of options available both on app and DB to get to the same point, but this mostly depends on your needs and company standards. I have seen companies where everything regarding data relations were app driven as well as these where it was all about the performance.

Comment: The idea of creating a view seams very straight forward and I like moving logic into DB. I will wait the remaining bounty time, and if noone else has a better idea, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Going this route you can also thing about using a stored procedure inside the SQL Server. This would be the best option for you if this entity has a single usage - to get some attributes assigned to an ID. DB driven systems are  performing better if created correctly plus code is changing quickly data remains for a long time - i.e. in near future you might decide that the fact JAVA starting form v.11 is paid only and too expensive, so you want to move to C#, having all relations in the DB you can start rewriting your app without disabling the current one, then compare side to side.

Comment: The only thing I would add is readability. If SQL Server isn't your comfortable place, what are you going to think when you come back to this in 6 months? `SELECT t1.[id], t1.[Att1], t1.[Att2], t2.[Att3], t3.[Att4]
FROM [Table1] t1
INNER JOIN [Table2] t2 ON t1.[id] = t2.[id]
INNER JOIN [Table3] t3 ON t1.[id] = t3.[id] AND t3.[current] = 1;`. Doing the `AND` on the `JOIN` is purely preference. Personally I prefer keeping it together with what I'm `JOIN`ing on, but go for what you understand the easiest

Comment: This is all down to company/project/personal preferences in the end. At some point you have to read the code either this is JAVA, T-SQL or anything else.